# Bythos and Sophia, Yuanshi Tianzun and Lingbao Tianzun

Tags: metaphysics, taoism

The Gnostic Bythos is that of a Monad, though I know it does not have benevolent connotations. Disregarding any sense of goodness/morality/仁, in what ways is it not synonymous with that of the Daoistic Yuanshi Tianzun?

And Sophia, wisdom, maybe capacity to discern, in what ways is this not synonymous with Lingbao Tianzun?

Thank you in advance.

Some rough definitions-

Gnosticism, group of heretical Christian belief system;

Bythos: Gnostic Monad, 'God of Abyss'

Sophia: Gnostic personification of soul/intellect, 'God of Wisdom'

Daojiao, set of Chinese thought based on Laozi and ZhouYi;

Yuanshi Tianzun: 'Principle Beginning Heavenly Lord', presents the Wuji, which I am conjecturing is a Monad

Lingbao Tianzun: 'Spiritual Treasure Heavenly Lord', presents the Taiji, the space within the Wuji that has form

Comment: If you can link references to these concepts where they are described it may help someone who would like to attempt an answer.

Comment: I have no academic sources on either subject, but Gnosticism and Taoism have many original texts for those who are interested in them

Comment: I was thinking of even Wikipedia type definitions so people are clear what it is you are referring to. For me, this is the first time I heard of these terms. That may be the case for others as well. It doesn't have to be an academic source.

Comment: Thank you, added, let me know if you have more suggestions

Comment: Thanks. I don't know an answer that helped me understand.